# Confusing CSS Positioning

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a practice website based off of the off-white website (https://www.off---white.com/en/US). A problem I am facing is when attempting to position the top tabs that being Shop, More, About, & Contact it moves the off-black™ text I have next to them. Is there anyway I can move the others to the right of the screen and leave the off-black™ on the left?

I have tried multiple things ranging from my own experimentation to reaching the 4th page of google.

My HTML

```
<div class="web-top">
  <div id="web-top-title">
    <p class="web-top-title-text">Off-Black™</p>
  </div>
  <div id="web-top-shop">
    <p class="web-top-shop-text">Shop</p>
  </div>
  <div id="web-top-more">
    <p class="web-top-more-text">More</p>
  </div>
  <div id="web-top-about">
    <p class="web-top-about-text">About</p>
  </div>
  <div id="web-top-contact">
    <p class="web-top-contact-text">Contact</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```css
/* Full Page Styling */
body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

/* Top Header Styling */
.web-top {
    color:white;
    background-color:blue;
    width:100%;
    height:22px;
    display:block;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#web-top-title, #web-top-shop, #web-top-more, #web-top-about, #web-top-contact {
    margin-top:-14px;
    float:left;
}

.web-top-title-text {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please read [ask], and [mcve], with the focus on _clear problem statement_.  "Confusing CSS Positioning" is not a very clear problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` and apply [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) for getting this UI.

```css
/* Full Page Styling */

body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* Top Header Styling */

.web-top {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#web-top-title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#web-top-shop,
#web-top-more,
#web-top-about,
#web-top-contact {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="web-top">
  <div id="web-top-title">
    <p class="web-top-title-text">Off-Black™</p>
  </div>
  <div id="web-top-shop">
    <p class="web-top-shop-text">Shop</p>
  </div>
  <div id="web-top-more">
    <p class="web-top-more-text">More</p>
  </div>
  <div id="web-top-about">
    <p class="web-top-about-text">About</p>
  </div>
  <div id="web-top-contact">
    <p class="web-top-contact-text">Contact</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That exactly what I needed. I am still wondering though now that they are over there how would I go about separating them from each other?

Comment: you mean spacing?

Comment: Yes. How would I go about spacing them from each other.

Comment: updated the code. I have taken off the height as i guess this is what you are after

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could float the elements you want on right to right

```
  .web-top {
    color:white;
    background-color:blue;
    width:100%;
    height:22px;
    display:block;
    margin-top:0px;
}
/* Top Header Styling */

 #web-top-title{
   float:left;
   margin-top:-14px;
   margin-left:10px;
 }

#web-top-shop,#web-top-more ,#web-top-about,#web-top-contact{

    float:right;
    margin-top:-14px;
}
```